# Selecting an option in drop down menu using Selenium

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium, combobox, webdriver

Can someone help me in selecting option **Inquiry** from below code? I have tried but failed.

---

```
<div class="SplitButton" id="HIRA_SPLITBUTTON" splitBtnName="pyDescription" btnType = "menu" onSplMenuClick='HIRA.ui.gadget.NewWork.StartProcess4Menu'>
    <select id="pyDescription">
        <option value='className&#61;HIRAFS-Work-Inquiry&amp;flowType&#61;Inquiry&amp;HarnessVersion&#61;1'> Inquiry </option>
        <option value='className&#61;HIRAFS-Work-Copy&amp;flowType&#61;Copy&amp;HarnessVersion&#61;1'> Copy </option>
    </select>
    <table class='buttonMainTable' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='' >
        <tr>
            <td class='buttonTdLeft'>
            <div class="buttonLeftContent">
                <div class="buttonLeftContentInner">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div></td><td class='buttonTdMiddle'>
            <button class='buttonTdButton' alt='' title='' HIRA_VERSION='HTMLPROPERTY' id='HIRA_SPLITBTNpyDescription'>
                <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign='top'><img src='desktopimages/new.gif' style='margin-top:-1px'/></td><td valign='middle' style='white-space:nowrap;'>New</td>
                    </tr>
                </table></span>
            </button></td><td class='buttonTdRight'>
            <div class="buttonRightContent">
                <div class="buttonRightContentInner">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @strah: How did you handle this [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/612169) review? The edit history here suggests you choose to edit the suggestion, but there is no record of the review action. Want to come over to [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170175/community-is-a-review-monkey-too/170176#170176) and add in your side of what happened here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have to reference the webdriver support dll to do the following.

```
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(element);
select.SelectByText("Inquiry");
```

If you are using Visual Studios with NuGet then you can go to your powershell and type

```
Install-Package Selenium.Support
```

and that will install all of the references and dlls that you need.

Comment: Had to leave this...for a while, got busy with something. I still cannot select